# why there is a difference in the magnetic values taken by different smartphones?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I need to record the magnetic data in the same surface by two smartphones.

I find different values of the magnitude of magnetic field knowing that I put my smartphones in the same place end the same height. The magnetometers are `YAS532(sensitivity 0.2µT/LSB, Measurement Range ±1200 µT )` and `AK09911(sensitivity  0.6µT/LSB, Measurement Range ±4900  µT )`.

Why the results are different while magnetic field is known to be constant and stable? How can I correct the values using the parameters of the magnetometers?

Comment: Ghost Hunters..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure the answer is just in the fact that you are using different sensors. I have not done much in this area, but simply from the robotics classes I took in school I know that different sensors, even of the exact same specifications, will just return different data, and the same sensor may even sometimes return different data. This is normal because there will always be random error. What you really need to do is take a lot of measurements and figure out what a normal range of error is, and then write your code based on that.

Answer (score 2):

Electrical engineering says magnetic field **cannot be same w.r.t place and time**. Magnetic fields changes - like when you bring watch near to compass and also as when earth rotates it gets changed.

So even if with some (*can't say what ?*) method you've attained fixed magnetic field smartphone circuit shall be changing field readings for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to obtain correct measurements is to use calibrated sensors. Even then, there will be some tolerance of values due to sensitivity of the sensors. In a proper laboratory, all measurement equipment is usually calibrated as a matter of routine practice. It is the only way to mitigate the symptoms you are also experiencing.

The two results of your sensors are very different, it is possible that one or both may be of low quality or affected by the electronics and components that surround it in the smartphones you mention using.

Try to find a known good sensor to use in your tests or see if a local academic department can help with calibrating the smartphones. Then you will have the information you need to continue with project.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the magnetic field is different at different time.. why dont you try with 2 models of same mobile and see if there is difference with the magnetic field.

Also, if the field is same for same model of mobile. 
i suspect the below for difference in reading from 2 type of sensors

1. May be some difference in sensor
2. the interference on phone components to the magnetic sensor.

Also try recalibration of the sensor